# Htaccess rewriteCond allows to browse directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, router

Im making a php script with router, and condition of it - write in htaccess file specific code - this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

But string `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` allows to browse all my directories with all scripts, like `example.com/server` (my server logic). Without it its pretty good. Is it so neccessary and why it added to script?

Comment: Add `Options -Indexes` at the top of your .htaccess to prevent directory listing.

Comment: Ok, thats work, and now apache throw this: `You don't have permission to access /server/ on this server.`. Thou I'd like to get standart 404 page by my php router. And it works this way without  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` string.